A question about permutation similarity of symmetric matrices
Let $A , B \in M_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$. Matrices $A, B$ are $\textbf{permutation similar}$ if there exists a permutation matrix such that $A= PBP^T$. Define $\mathrm{diag}(A)$ to be the vector of diagonal entries of the matrix $A$. Suppose we are given the following symmetric, non-negative matrices with same diagonals: $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}\bf a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14} \\ a_{12}&\bf a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\ a_{13}&a_{23}&\bf a_{33}&a_{34}\\ a_{14}&a_{24}&a_{34}&\bf a_{44} \end{bmatrix},~B= \begin{bmatrix} \bf a_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}&b_{14} \\ b_{12}&\bf a_{22}&b_{23}&b_{24}\\ b_{13}&b_{23}&\bf a_{33}&b_{34}\\ b_{14}&b_{24}&b_{34}&\bf a_{44}  \end{bmatrix}$$  Suppose further that $\mathrm{diag}(A^k) = \mathrm{diag}(B^k)$ for $1 \leq k \leq 4$. (This, besides other properties, tells us that the matrices have the same characteristic polynomials) I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are permutation similar. I approached this first by comparing the polynomial equations and trying to solve for the unknowns. I hoped to find relations of the kind $a_{ij} = b_{k\ell}$. It leads me to the following list of equations I can no longer simplify.

Comparing the coefficients of $x^2$ in the characteristic polynomial: $$ a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2 + a_{14}^2 + a_{23}^2 + a_{24}^2 + a_{34}^2 = b_{12}^2 + b_{13}^2 + b_{14}^2 + b_{23}^2 + b_{24}^2 + b_{34}^2 ~~(1)$$

Comparing the entries in the vector equality $\mathrm{diag}(A^2) = \mathrm{diag}(B^2)$: $$ a_{12}^2 + a_{13}^2 + a_{14}^2 = b_{12}^2 + b_{13}^2 + b_{14}^2 ~~(2)$$ $$  a_{12}^2 + a_{23}^2 + a_{24}^2 = b_{12}^2 + b_{23}^2 + b_{24}^2 ~~(3)$$ $$ a_{13}^2 + a_{23}^2 + a_{34}^2 = b_{13}^2 + b_{23}^2 + b_{34}^2  ~~(4) $$ $$ a_{14}^2 + a_{24}^2 + a_{34}^2  = b_{14}^2 + b_{24}^2 + b_{34}^2 ~~ (5)$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x$ in the characteristic polynomial: $$ a_{12}a_{13}a_{23} + a_{13}a_{14}a_{34} + a_{12}a_{14}a_{24} + a_{23}a_{24}a_{34} = b_{12}b_{13}b_{23} + b_{13}b_{14}b_{34} + b_{12}b_{14}b_{24} + b_{23}b_{24}b_{34} ~~(6)$$


After failing to solve the system by hand, I tried using the sage function 'solve' but it didn't give me any solutions. I am now unsure if this system is even solvable or if I am trying it wrong.
I did not want to clutter the post with more equations, but I can write down the characteristic polynomial or the other equations we get from the diagonal equality condition if that can be helpful. As always, I'll be grateful if someone can offer some directions on this.

$B = DAD^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal non multiple of identity

I am slightly confused. Could you elaborate a bit more? @Exodd

It's a counterexample. Try by yourself with any D

By non-multiple of identity, do you mean a matrix where the off-diagonal entries are zero but diagonal entries are not all the same?

Yes, and it must be invertible

@Exodd I asked for a symmetric matrix though

a permutation changes the order of the elements on the diagonal, so unless you have repeated entrie, you are actually trying to prove that $A=B$

I see what you're saying. I should have clarified what I meant by $diag(A^k) = diag(B^k)$. The original assumption was that the diagonals are equal up to permutation: $diag(A^k) = \pi diag(B^k)$ for some $\pi$. This is the same as requiring that for some matrices $M$ and $N$ that are permutation similar to $A$ and $B$ respectively, $diag(M^k) = diag(N^k)$. So, you're right, unless there are repeated entries, I am trying to show that $M = N$, which would mean that $A$ is permutation similar to $B$.
